# go websockets with gorilla libs - unknown json response so can't map it

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I am a newbee, and I am trying to connect to a website that uses websocket for many things, including a chat.
my goal is to get only the chat output and do something with that and ignore the rest.

I know the json I am expecting for the chat, but not for the rest, so when I run the program I get now all the websocket output, but im only interested in:

```
[null,null,"channel:zRAMDON","message",{"session_id":"ramdon-d655-4ee1-ramdon","body":"TEST!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!","type":"chat"}]
```

now I'm using to catch all

```
var readCHAT []interface{}

go func() {
        for {
            
            err := ws.ReadJSON(&readCHAT)

            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error read: %s", err)
                break
            }
            log.Printf("Message received: %+v", readCHAT)
        }
    }()
```

the problem I have is that I get diff websocket msg's so can't just write a one struct.

a example of websocket I get that **I do not need** as many others I want to ignore:

```
[<nil> <nil> channel:zRAMDON naf map[data:map[components:map[0:map[x:18.37785615655833 y:3.849238250917483 z:31.306368728428566] 1:map[x:-2.1127290916182298e-13 y:-14.000000000000544 z:1.6920595533305515e-13] 10:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 11:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 12:false 2:map[x:1.0000000000000018 y:1.0000000000000713 z:0.999999999999999] 3:map[avatarSrc:https://somewhere.com/api/v1/avatars/PcJ8Sxb/avatar.gltf?v=63726570330 avatarType:skinnable muted:true] 4:map[left_hand_pose:0 right_hand_pose:0] 5:map[x:0 y:1.6 z:0] 6:map[x:5.21773538958394 y:41.12499999998135 z:-3.292556714059138e-11] 7:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 8:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 9:false] creator:f6ee84ab-15af-4bc0-b9df-aa9c71093118 isFirstSync:true lastOwnerTime:1.5933988881835e+12 networkId:m9ms3qv owner:f6ee84ab-15af-4bc0-b9df-aa9c71093118 parent:<nil> persistent:false template:#remote-avatar] dataType:u from_session_id:f6ee84ab-15af-4bc0-b9df-aa9c71093118]]
```

how can I work with only the json I need if I can't convert it to a struct to use map[] etc etc when I am not sure what I am getting.

IDEAL: if I could just somehow dynamically search the interface and if the json is the one I expect then put it into objets in a struct... or similar..

thanks

[edit]

diff examples that I need to ignore:

```
[<nil> <nil> channel:zRAMDON naf map[data:map[components:map[0:map[x:4.001814822517539 y:2.644030847036413 z:30.97952900553247] 1:map[x:2.4521572390556376e-13 y:-14.000000000000105 z:8.633353546977925e-15] 10:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 11:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 12:false 2:map[x:1 y:1.0000000000000715 z:1.0000000000000009] 3:map[avatarSrc:https://somesite.com/api/v1/avatars/3IADk9x/avatar.gltf?v=63743924756 avatarType:skinnable muted:true] 4:map[left_hand_pose:0 right_hand_pose:0] 5:map[x:0 y:1.6 z:0] 6:map[x:-7.540983606551728 y:111.09374999994142 z:-4.904411738530524e-11] 7:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 8:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 9:false] creator:de96a126-cf5f-48b2-8c0c-02d79b4382d5 isFirstSync:true lastOwnerTime:1.5934383934451e+12 networkId:5jwrz57 owner:de96a126-cf5f-48b2-8c0c-02d79b4382d5 parent:<nil> persistent:false template:#remote-avatar] dataType:u from_session_id:de96a126-cf5f-48b2-8c0c-02d79b4382d5]]
```

another one:

```
[<nil>  phoenix phx_reply map[response:map[] status:ok]]
```

another one this one is like the most I get but I DO NOT need, so need to filter all of it out:

```
[<nil> <nil> channel:zRAMDON naf map[data:map[components:map[0:map[x:4.001814822517539 y:2.644030847036413 z:30.97952900553247] 1:map[x:2.4521572390556376e-13 y:-14.000000000000105 z:8.633353546977925e-15] 10:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 11:map[x:0 y:0 z:0] 12:false 2:map[x:1 y:1.0000000000000715 z:1.0000000000000009] 3:map[avatarSrc:https://somesite.com/api/v1/avatars/3IADk9x/avatar.gltf?v=63743924756 avatarType:skinnable muted:true] 4:map[left_hand_pose:0
```

those AND LIKE 100 other ones that are even more different and not even the same patter, if they had all the same pattern but diff content then it will be easy to write a struct and get a idea of the json document.

here is what I actually need:

```
[null,null,"channel:zRAMDON","message",{"session_id":"ramdon-d655-4ee1-ramdon","body":"TEST!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!","type":"chat"}]
```

So I need to somehow get filter/get rid of and then from this response I could maybe write a struct to put in the null, null, channel, message etc

thanks for the help. this is driving me crazy

EDIT2:

ok  I have open the websocket network tab of chrome dev tools:
I notice there is always an array of 4 elements then this opens to a json at the end. but this json is always diff and the descryptions so far are obscure:

```
["2", "238", "hub:zWXK8U6", "nafr", {,…}]
0: "2"
1: "238"
2: "room:zRAMDON"
3: "nafr"
4: {,…}
naf: "{"dataType":"um","data":{"d":[{"networkId":"A8AFC029-A3AF-459B-AC89-83557814DEAC","owner":"fa477e9d-7e92-4c1d-9b7b-6e9e0e975495","creator":"","lastOwnerTime":1593446129608,"template":"#static-controlled-media","persistent":true,"parent":null,"components":{"1":169.509434}}]}}"
```

another similar but diff on 3 element:

```
"2", "237", "room:zRAMDON", "naf",…]
0: "2"
1: "237"
2: "room:zRAMDON"
3: "naf"
4: {dataType: "u", data: {networkId: "mi2p4c5", owner: "fa477e9d-7e92-4c1d-9b7b-6e9e0e975495",…}}
data: {networkId: "mi2p4c5", owner: "fa477e9d-7e92-4c1d-9b7b-6e9e0e975495",…}
components: {0: {x: -0.4637117156600495, y: 2.255, z: 8.3544556410586}, 1: {x: 0, y: -14.000000000000009, z: 0},…}
0: {x: -0.4637117156600495, y: 2.255, z: 8.3544556410586}
1: {x: 0, y: -14.000000000000009, z: 0}
2: {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
3: {,…}
4: {left_hand_pose: 0, right_hand_pose: 0}
5: {x: 0, y: 1.6, z: 0}
6: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
7: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
8: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
9: false
10: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
11: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
12: false
creator: "fa477e9d-7e92-4c1d-9b7b-6e9e0e975495"
isFirstSync: true
lastOwnerTime: 1593446133299
networkId: "mi2p4c5"
owner: "fa477e9d-7e92-4c1d-9b7b-6e9e0e975495"
parent: null
persistent: false
template: "#remote-avatar"
dataType: "u"
```

and yet another example:

```
[null, "235", "phoenix", "heartbeat", {}]
0: null
1: "235"
2: "phoenix"
3: "heartbeat"
4: {}
```

and the one I actually need:

```
[null, null, "room:zRAMDON", "message", {session_id: "fa477e9d-7e92-4c1d-9b7b-6e9e0e975495",…}]
0: null
1: null
2: "room:zRAMDON"
3: "message"
4: {session_id: "fa477e9d-7e92-4c1d-9b7b-6e9e0e975495",…}
body: "testtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt"
session_id: "fa477e9d-7e92-4c1d-9b7b-6e9e0e975495"
type: "chat"
```

so is clear there is a json array of 5 elements the problem is after element 3.  I have try to parse all this into a auto json to go struct tool and even the tool gets confused and spits errors..

ok so I am not sure what im doing but I have combined 3 diff json outputs into one like:

```
type WebSocketHubs []WebSocketHubElement

type WebSocketHubClass struct {
    SessionID string `json:"session_id"`
    Body      string `json:"body"`
    Type      string `json:"type"`
    DataType  string `json:"dataType"`
    Data      Data   `json:"data"`
}

type WebSocketHubElement struct {
    String            *string
    WebSocketHubClass *WebSocketHubClass
}

type Data struct {
    NetworkID     string                     `json:"networkId"`
    Owner         string                     `json:"owner"`
    Creator       string                     `json:"creator"`
    LastOwnerTime int64                      `json:"lastOwnerTime"`
    Template      string                     `json:"template"`
    Persistent    bool                       `json:"persistent"`
    Parent        interface{}                `json:"parent"`
    Components    map[string]*ComponentValue `json:"components"`
    IsFirstSync   bool                       `json:"isFirstSync"`
}

type ComponentClass struct {
    X             *float64 `json:"x,omitempty"`
    Y             *float64 `json:"y,omitempty"`
    Z             *float64 `json:"z,omitempty"`
    AvatarSrc     *string  `json:"avatarSrc,omitempty"`
    AvatarType    *string  `json:"avatarType,omitempty"`
    Muted         *bool    `json:"muted,omitempty"`
    LeftHandPose  *int64   `json:"left_hand_pose,omitempty"`
    RightHandPose *int64   `json:"right_hand_pose,omitempty"`
}

type ComponentValue struct {
    Bool           *bool
    ComponentClass *ComponentClass
}
```

but now I get:

Error read: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.WebSocketHubClass

:(

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to unmarshal JSON documents with different structure. Edit the question to show examples of the JSON documents.  This problem is only related to WebSockets because that's where you got the JSON document from.

Comment: hello thats the issue.. I have no idea of the json Im going to get from the websocket... is like hundreds of diff responses in json format from it, I only know of 1 format for the chat.

Comment: Assuming that all users of the application protocol will have this problem, it's likely that a value in the JSON document describes the type of the JSON document. If so, you can use that value to look for the messages of interest.  Show some examples of the JSON documents.

Comment: https://github.com/tidwall/gjson, this helps?

Comment: @MuffinTop hello thanks again for the reply, there is already one generic example on my post, I have put first the json I want, and later an example of one I do not want but I still get among many others on the same socket. I have count around 140 diff json responses or documents like you call it. my question is how to ignore all this and only grab the one I need?  im the only user doing this, is a new service and I am creating a bridge between this service and another chat room, So there is no documentation.

Comment: There is insufficient information in the question to determine how the messages you want are distinguished from other messages .  Showing more messages in JSON format might help.

Comment: @MuffinTop well that is exactly the issue, Im asking how does people do this when they do not know what json they getting, I can put it all on a []interface{} but now I need to grep or search for the info I need, and only get that, each json document is diff always. because the information changes constantly when on the websocket channel there are thousands of events that happen with diff json formats. one idea was, ok I treat it and see if the strings contain "chat" and if thats the case then formated manually and do something with the info.. but then I though there HAS to be a better way

Comment: Look at the pattern in the documents to find what distinguishes the different document types.   Once that's known, partially unmarshal the documents to extract that value and then unmarshal the remainder based on that type.  We are stuck at distinguishing the different document types.

Comment: @MuffinTop I though of that, but they really have nothing in common in between them, and most times lot of arrays are complicated and null or nill,  funny enought the one I need is simple.  one example of json I get I will put above gime me 10m so I can run my client

Comment: Does the 4th element of the array describes the type of the 5th element?

Comment: @MuffinTop thanks for keeping up with my silly question :) I apriciate it.  I have updated the question again with clearer output, from chrome dev tools websocket network tab. and is clear there is an array with some values and the number of items in the array seems the same on all json websocket traffic.. the problem is the last elements. so seems like 3 according to the tool is the one conditioning the type after.

Comment: @MuffinTop updated the question with more info and I created some structs but still not working... this json is way complicated for my limited knowladge all the examples I see online are with plain simple json, not this complicated dynamic json arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I got tired of no help and no clear documentation and just did the brutebruce approach and used the call to array and maps,  and then compare strings to get what I needed.

```
      var leerCHAT []interface{}

    for {
        //line, message, err := ws.ReadMessage()
        err := ws.ReadJSON(&leerCHAT)

        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error read: %s", err)
            break
        }
        log.Printf("Message received: %v", leerCHAT[2])
        if leerCHAT[3] == "message" {
            //var cookie string
            cookie := leerCHAT[4].(map[string]interface{})
            log.Printf("el chat dice: %s", cookie["body"].(string))
            chatMSG := cookie["body"].(string)
            go MatrixSay(matrixClient, chatMSG, matrixChannel)

        }

    }
```

I changed this with the help of another question, that I had another issue but ended up refactoring the whole thing.
[Whats the best way to get content from a generic and somehow dynamic go map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698268/whats-the-best-way-to-get-content-from-a-generic-and-somehow-dynamic-go-map/62698912?noredirect=1#comment110885129_62698912)