# Whats the best way to get content from a generic and somehow dynamic go map?

Tags: go, hashmap, gorilla

I have this json that I convert to:

```
var leerCHAT []interface{}
```

but I am going through crazy hoops to get to any point on that map inside map and inside map crazyness, specially because some results are different content.
this is the Json

```
[
   null,
   null,
   "hub:zWXroom",
   "presence_diff",
   {
      "joins":{
         "f718a187-6e96-4d62-9c2d-67aedea00000":{
            "metas":[
               {
                  "context":{},
                  "permissions":{},
                  "phx_ref":"zNDwmfsome=",
                  "phx_ref_prev":"zDMbRTmsome=",
                  "presence":"lobby",
                  "profile":{},
                  "roles":{}
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "leaves":{}
   }
]
```

I need to get to profile then inside there is a "DisplayName" field.

so I been doing crazy hacks.. and even like this I got stuck half way...

First is an array so I can just do something[elementnumber]
then is when the tricky mapping starts...
SORRY about all the prints etc is to debug and see the number of elements I am getting back.

```
if leerCHAT[3] == "presence_diff" {
                var id string
                presence := leerCHAT[4].(map[string]interface{})
                log.Printf("algo: %v", len(presence))
                log.Printf("algo: %s", presence["joins"])
                vamos := presence["joins"].(map[string]interface{})
                for i := range vamos {
                    log.Println(i)
                    id = i
                }
                log.Println(len(vamos))

                vamonos := vamos[id].(map[string]interface{})
                log.Println(vamonos)
                log.Println(len(vamonos))

                metas := vamonos["profile"].(map[string]interface{})   \\\ I get error here..

                log.Println(len(metas))
            }
```

so far I can see all the way to the meta:{...}  but can't continue with my hacky code into what I need.

NOTICE: that since the id after Joins: and before metas: is dynamic I have to get it somehow since is always just one element I did the for range loop to grab it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array element at index 3 describes the type of the variant JSON at index 4.

Here's how to decode the JSON to Go values.  First, declare Go types for each of the variant parts of the JSON:

```
type PrescenceDiff struct {
     Joins map[string]*Presence // declaration of Presence type to be supplied
     Leaves map[string]*Presence
}

type Message struct {
     Body string
}
```

Declare a map associating the type string to the Go type:

```
var messageTypes = map[string]reflect.Type{
    "presence_diff": reflect.TypeOf(&PresenceDiff{}),
    "message":       reflect.TypeOf(&Message{}),
    // add more types here as needed
}
```

Decode the variant part to a [raw message](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage). Use use the name in the element at index 3 to create a value of the appropriate Go type and decode to that value:

```
func decode(data []byte) (interface{}, error) {
    var messageType string
    var raw json.RawMessage
    v := []interface{}{nil, nil, nil, &messageType, &raw}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if len(raw) == 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("no message")
    }

    t := messageTypes[messageType]
    if t == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown message type: %q", messageType)
    }

    result := reflect.New(t.Elem()).Interface()
    err = json.Unmarshal(raw, result)
    return result, err
}
```

Use [type switches](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) to access the variant part of the message:

```
defer ws.Close()

for {
    _, data, err := ws.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Read error: %v", err)
        break
    }

    v, err := decode(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Decode error: %v", err)
        continue
    }

    switch v := v.(type) {
    case *PresenceDiff:
        fmt.Println(v.Joins, v.Leaves)
    case *Message:
        fmt.Println(v.Body)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("type %T not handled\n", v)
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iBn_OhUYIU1).

Comment: this is amazing, thanks so much, maybe I should add I am usign the gorilla/websocket libs, using  err := ws.ReadJSON(&leerCHAT)   <-- this to put it on the generic []interface{}  so with your example I will sent it to decode func? I think the gorilla ReadJSON() expects a interface hopefully im wrong. is why I did []interface{} first. will be nice to understand this piece since is prob what got me in the wrong direction to behind with.  @iLoveReflection

Comment: The problem is that each websocket response is diff so what ReadJSON reads is diff many times, and I dont have the json documents to bas, I'm basically reverse engineering with the browser the responses. so I already have working a part that is getting another json, that works great and I used the maps approach, now im trying to get the join/leaves that is a diff json but comes from the same websocket, this is why I check if element [3] if is presence_diff then I do something, so I will like to sent to decode the leerCHAT[3] but cannot convert leerCHAT[3] to byte is interface  iLoveReflection

Comment: so this is what I already have and is working https://gitlab.com/rek2/gohubsbot/-/blob/master/websocketsListen.go  but Im adding another IF to grab the presence_diff  I know is very hacky hopefully I learn json/maps in go well after all this.

Comment: awesome I think I got it!!! I did a fast test check it out here and see if this is what you have in mind, https://play.golang.org/p/CHlwY7Kr4kJ 
def much better approach than what I had :D

Comment: I implemented your changes, pls check the gitlab link again, I am  getting and error when is trying to unmarshall.
2020/07/02 18:56:19 Decode error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field PresenceDiff.Joins of type string
2020/07/02 18:56:22 Decode error: unknown message type
2020/07/02 18:56:22 Decode error: unknown message type
2020/07/02 18:56:23 Decode error: unknown message type
2020/07/02 18:56:24 Decode error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field PresenceDiff.Joins of type string
2020/07/02 18:56:26 Decode error: unknown message type

Comment: the chat does work fine still with your changes. using the decode so thats good :)

Comment: thats what I though, lookin now into changing it, was not sure if you did it for a reason or it was just a placeholder. thanks again

Comment: actually now that I am looking, this takes me to square 1, because inside that there are many maps like 10 more... and I have no clue and there is NO examples on how to go into each, this is why I went the maps route after looking for examples converting from json.. since is not as easy as map:objet is map:map:map:objet1,object2,objet3  I did not look at the playground json data though it was the whole json and you were ignoring somehow in the fuct what is not needed down into profile... :(

Comment: like in your example still does not solve my biggest problem... the json doc is diff when looking for profile. because the ID is part of the json key not objet and this key changes... this is why I had a for range so im down to where I started since json does not work for me maps do somehow.

Comment: maybe my question should had been different, I did say in the explanation the issue with the ID changing each request... there are plenty of json to golang struct tools, but none or none of the blogs/questions I read tells me how to bypass a key I dont know, so cant create a go struct from something I dont know, is imposible. the key in the example above is not always the same  "f718a187-6e96-4d62-9c2d-67aedea00000": changes! depending on who is that joins or leaves so how can I make a struct out of something that we dont know such why I did the maps and used a for range in the map to find out

Comment: and sorry if I sound dry, im thankfull just this comments wont allow me to type a lot and give details sorry

Comment: Please examine the code in my answer and the linked playground example.  Use a map when keys are not known at compile time.  Example from my answer: `Joins map[string]*Presence`.   The value `f718a187-6e96-4d62-9c2d-67aedea00000` is a key in this map.

Comment: looking now thanks, that looks like is actually what I am looking for since is using maps so I can get the key I need and continue, thanks again.

Comment: ok I think im getting it for most part, I added a new struct for Profile to include AvatarID and DisplayName, still after reading some examples on blogs cant see to get to print DisplayName :(  all examples I see are easy simple examples, I can print with out a problem v.Joins["Meta"] etc but cant get to go down structs pass that, can you please show me a example to print and objet pass the map? I tried chaining like v.Joins[].Profile.etc and similar combinations v.Joins prints the id fine, but cant pass from there like https://medium.com/wesionary-team/structs-and-maps-in-golang-15c7ac08db31

Comment: you are awesome thank you, so at the end I still need to follow a for range loop to pass the map piece into the next structs, this is where I got confused though that maybe with this approach It will avoid that, guess not. thank you going to try it and make sense of it so next time I don't have to ask silly questions over the internet :D